# How to implement overloaded operators for polymorphic quantities in Fortran 200x

Tags: oop, fortran, polymorphism, operator-overloading, derived-class

I am trying to implement some high-level field handling in my Fortran code. My struggle is on execution speed, but at the same time I would like to exploit all of the best that modern Fortran paradigms allow.

I have essentially an abstract base type that extends into multiple types:

```
module fields
  use domains, only: domain_type => domain
  implicit none
  private

  type, abstract, public :: field
      character(12)  :: name
      character(256) :: description
      integer        :: tag

      type(domain_type), pointer :: domain => null()

      contains

      ! Some deferred type-bound procedures
      procedure(init_proc), deferred :: field_init
      ! ...

      ! Some deferred overloaded operators
      procedure(assign_proc), private, deferred :: field_assign
      generic :: assignment(=) => field_assign
      ! ...

  end type field

  ! ...

end module fields
```

My subtypes are implemented in other source files:

```
module cell_scalar_fields
   use fields
   implicit none
   private

   type, public, extends(field) :: cell_scalar_field
      ! Field variable
      real(8), allocatable :: var(:)
      ! ... other contents ...
      contains
      ! list of procedures 
   end type cell_scalar_field
contains
  ! ... procedures
end module cell_scalar_fields
```

and

```
module cell_vector_fields
   use fields
   implicit none
   private

   type, public, extends(field) :: cell_vector_field
      ! Field variable
      type(vector3d), allocatable :: var(:)
      ! ... other contents ...
      contains
      ! list of procedures 
   end type cell_vector_field

contains

  ! ... procedures
end module cell_vector_fields
```

I am now trying to implement overloaded operations corresponding to assignment, product, sum, division, including either subtype (scalar_field/scalar_field, scalar_field/vector_field, vector_field/vector_field) and operations with scalar constants.

As you can see from the implementation, the operations would barely correspond to fast array multiplication/sum operations, plus some further pieces of information that need to be carried on with the field type.

Trying to comply with the modern Fortran standard, I am doing something like this for each operation:

```
 subroutine cell_scalar_field_assignment(this,that)
 class(cell_scalar_field)  , intent(inout) :: this
 class(field)              , intent(in)  :: that
 ! Local variables
 class(field)              , pointer     :: infield
 integer                                 :: ncells,domainid

 select type (infield => that)
    type is (scalar_cell_field)
       if (.not.this%allocated()) then
          ncells = size(infield%var)
          allocate(this%var(ncells))
          ! ...
          this%name = infield%name
          this%descr = infield%descr
          this%tag = infield%tag
          domainid = infield%domain%id
          this%domain => domains(domainid)
       endif
       this%var=infield%var
       this%revar=infield%revar
    class default
       write(*,*) this_module,' Method to assign field <',infield%type_name(),'> to <',this%type_name(),'> not yet implemented.'
       stop
 end select
 end subroutine cell_scalar_field_assignment
```

This approach however has issues:

- when cross-writing routines for scalar/vector field operations in both modules, will I encounter a circular dependency of the source files. However, I just really do not want to have a unique module with tenths of thousands lines of code that includes all extended types in it...?
- I am forced to allocate those fields in each routine (I've been able to avoid it by using `intent(inout)` in the assignment, maybe is it gfortran that allows this?), my fear is that everything will be terribly slow when computing expressions such as `y = a*(x+z) - (B.dot.C)` etc. : using plain arrays, that would be solved with a simpler and extremely fast expression similar to `y = a*(x+z) - (dot_product(B,C))`.
  I think the solution would be if I can overcome the field allocation issue and somehow directly use the `%var` contents in each field type directly, but without having to specify `%var` everywhere such as in `y%var = a*(x%var+z%var) - (dot_product(B%var,C%var))`. But, is there a way to do it?

Thanks a lot in advance, any pieces of advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: nope, I'm using gfortran 4.9.2 but no version up to 6 does...

Comment: They are scheduled to the final version 6.

Comment: I don't get your point 2, can you say more about it?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks for your replies. If I used `real(8), allocatable, dimension(:)` instead than my field type, I could compute that dummy algebraic expression many times without losing time allocating/deallocating temporaries: I could use the `save` attribute, or initialize those fields in a module only once and re-use them, or even use static arrays. I would like to do something similar with my derived field type, to make the simulation much faster. I don't know if there is any workaround for the overloaded operator definition that would allow something like that (like using `save`)

Comment: I don't get the bit about intent(inout), you should probably show the code. BTW if you care about modern programming, don't use an ugliness like `real(8)`.

Comment: I can use `intent(inout)` to define an overloaded assignment, but not to define an overloaded operator (such as `operator(*)`), where I need to provide a `class(field), allocatable` as the output of the corresponding function: otherwise I will get a 
`CLASS variable 'new'  must be dummy, allocatable or pointer` error

Comment: Please show the code, it is very confusing to try decipher the comments. You say something about allocating temporaries and there is not a single allocate() in your question.

Comment: BTW, first defining `infield` as a pointer and than using it as an associate name in a `select type` seems suspicious to me.

Comment: For the first point, using "include" or #include (plus cpp macro if necessary) might be useful (but not very sure for circular dependence). For the second point, AFAIK, eliminating array temporaries within the current Fortran may be impossible... It is not clear how to do "lazy evaluation" with user-defined types  (like expression templates http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html ) But if it's possible I would also like to learn it :D

Comment: If the compiler allows pointer return variables (as left-hand side) and at the same time the Fortran standard allows the overload of parenthesis (), then it may be useful to overload () to a function returning a pointer to var(:), but I guess the parenthesis () are not allowed to be overloaded.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, that might be better addressed elsewhere.  Cyclic dependencies can sometimes be managed with using external procedures to break the cycle.  In terms of point 2, if you have not already done so, perhaps have a read of "Scientific Software Design" by Rouson, Xia and Xu.  It deals with some of the design aspects for code like this.  Having access to a Fortran 2008 compiler would also help.

Comment: All, thanks for your comments. @roygvib I am building a further `field_operations` module file containing all of them and their interfaces. I'll have to `use` two modules but that should solve the dependency issue. @IanH Yep, that is the book that plunged me into the OO Fortran world! I eventually thought that the best thing would be to use _parametrized derived types_: all fields in my problem have the same size and the allocation is only meant to initialize them: (as for plain arrays) I could define operations that only work with same-sized fields. But does any compiler feature them?